# Configure SQL Server to allow LAN connection

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to configure SQL Server to allow LAN connection but I do not seem to have any luck.

I am using the default server name and have created a new SQL Server user with a username and password.

I have also enabled Named Pipes and TCP\IP from SQL Server Configuration Manager and then reset the server.

I have tested the user on the local computer witch will act as the server

It seems that the client PC throws this error:

[image]

I usually get this error when I type the wrong server name this leads me to believe that I might need to add some additional configuration.

Can anyone point me the right direction on what I have to do next?

Comment: I'd have expected it to be \\COMPUTERNAME or when using an instance \\COMPUTERNAME\INSTANCENAME. If those don't work then make sure TCP/IP is enabled on the server. That the ports for SqlServer and SQL Browser are allowed through any firewall, SQLBrowser service is running. Last ditch effort would be use the IP address instead of the name in case DNS is not resolving the server name

Comment: Also, please right click on the server node in sqlserver administrator and select properties. Then select the "Connections" list view item on the left hand side and make sure "Enable Remote Connections" is checked.

Comment: Check firewall settings both at the server and client PC - make sure that SQL Server network ports are allowed.